# -/bin/sh: .memtester: not found

Tags: qemu, busybox

I want to use memtester(4.5.1) to test my system, which is runned on qemu-system-aarch64.Then I package the builded memtester dir to rootfs.cpio.gz. When I cd memtster-4.5.1 dir in my system, input '''./memtester 1024M 10''', failed. output:'''-/bin/sh: ./memtester: not found''', can anyone help me ? please ~

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the dynamic library of the runtime dependency is missing.
Solution: Package the lib64 and libc directories under the cross-compilation toolchain to the file system of busybox.